# Regex Javascript Starts with AB 0-9 and then ends with A-Z as optional it could be AB00001 or AB00001A (as optional)

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^AB+[0-9A-Z?]+$
```

Javascript Regex Starts with AB 0-9 and then ends with A-Z as optional it could be AB00001 or AB00001A (as optional)

Strings which should work AB00001 , AB000001B , AB12122 , AB00001C with any capital letter as a n optional

Comment: `^AB\d+[A-Z]?$`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried `^AB+[0-9A-Z?]+$` matches:

- Single `A` char
- 1+ times `B` char
- 1+ times any of the specified ranges 0-9 A-Z or a `?` char.

It can match for example `ABB???`

---

You could write the pattern matching a single A and single B char, then 1+ digits and optionally match a char A-Z according to the example data.

```
^AB\d+[A-Z]?$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E9KJJI/1)